# Dynamically concatenating strings

Tags: r

I have this static text `https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500`. I want to concatenate this string with the other string `&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=PM10`. The second string should be added dynamically based on the conditions shown in the list below.

```
cond=list(city=c("Mumbai,Delhi"), polutant_id=c("PM10,NO2"))
```

The output below contains 4 string as the above list has 4 possible combination of city and polutant_id.

**Output**

```
"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=PM10"

"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Delhi&filters[polutant_id]=PM10"

"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=NO2"

"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Delhi&filters[polutant_id]=NO2"
```

**Note :** There can be more or less than two elements in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in base R you can use `sprintf` to format the strings accordingly:

```
const <-"https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500"    
fmt <- '%s&filters[city]=%s&filters[polutant_id]=%s' #Note the placement of %s
```

You can then do:

```
do.call(sprintf, c(fmt, const, expand.grid(sapply(cond, strsplit,','))))


[1] "https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=PM10"
[2] "https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Delhi&filters[polutant_id]=PM10" 
[3] "https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Mumbai&filters[polutant_id]=NO2" 
[4] "https://api.xxx.com/resource/xxx?api-key=xxx&format=json&limit=500&filters[city]=Delhi&filters[polutant_id]=NO2"
```

Note that if you have a literal `%` in the format string `fmt` you will have to escape it by having double `%%`. learn more on [`sprintf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works like a charm. Is it possible to make it work even if there is more or less than two elements in the list. For e.g. if only city. Or 3 elements - city, state and pollutant_id?

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari you will have to dynamically create the `fmt` string. eg `fmt <- paste0('%s', paste0('&filters[', names(cond), ']=%s', collapse = ''))`